# Как создать create форму с select в index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form, select2

Уже какой день ломаю голову с *Ruby on Rails 5*. Не могу создать `create form` вложенного атрибута `todo` с `select option` по project на одной странице (index)

Вот контроллер

```
def index
  @projects = Project.all
  @todo = Todo.new
end
```

Модели `project` и `todo`

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :todos, inverse_of: :project

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :todos, reject_if: proc { |attributes| 
  attributes[:title].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end

class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :todos
end
```

routes.rb

```
root 'projects#index'
    resources :projects do
        resources :todos
    end
```

`project/index.html.erb` (отображает всю БД, которая задается через `seed.yml`)

```
<h1>Задачи</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>   
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% for project in @projects %>
  <tr><strong><%= project.title %></strong></tr>
  <% for todo in project.todos %>
    <ul>
    <li><%= todo.text %></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Стайлгайд сообщества [не рекомендует использовать `for`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-for-loops). Это так, к сведению. Так куда именно вы хотите добавить поле?

Comment: Я хочу создать create форму, которая будет создавать todo в определенный project.title, который будет выбираться с  помощью select

Comment: Ок. Что уже есть? Хоть какое-нибудь создание `Todo` уже реализовано?

Comment: Нет, я не понимаю, как создать Todo в контроллере и индексе Project

Comment: Не-не, секунду. То, где форма рисуется, и куда она обращается, это отдельные места, и совпадать они не обязаны. Форма рисуется в `projects#index`, ок, а `todos#create` есть у вас?

Comment: Только @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)

Comment: Понял. Нету, то есть.

Comment: @2manov, думаете, международное сообщество добрее, раз дублируете там? :) Я только что отвечала там на очень похожий вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110956/mn-relation-error-in-rails?noredirect=1#comment85228728_49110956 Хватит, чтобы начать

Comment: @Василиса, я просто уже какой день ломаю над этим голову и первый раз пишу на форуме что-то, обычно только гуглю. И сейчас чувствую себя рыбой не в своей тарелке, поэтому решил на английском тоже написать, их коммьюнити все таки больше чем наше

Comment: @2manov, мне тут попался годный туториал на тему - https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/. Ну а вообще в реальной жизни для этого пользуются гемами вроде cocoon, они сильно облегчают жизнь

Comment: @2manov И только перечитав в 8-й раз вопрос, я поняла, что вам там вообще не нужны nested_attributes... Вроде вам ответили подробно на основном СО, получилось?

Comment: @Василиса Нет, они просто по другому переписали отображение всех `project.title` и `project.todos`. Но именно на мой вопрос "Как в определенный `project.title` через `select` добавить `todo`?" не ответили(

Answer (score 0):

Список проектов лучше через итератор отобразить в `project/index.html.erb`:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <tr><strong><%= project.title %></strong></tr>
  <% project.todos.each do |todo| %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= todo.text %></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
render 'todos/todo_form'
```

Рендеринг формы для добавления задачи в `project/index.html.erb`(в принципе в любой вьюхе, где надо вывести форму для todo) ([Рендеринг](http://rusrails.ru/layouts-and-rendering-in-rails#ispolzovanie-render)):

```
render 'todos/todo_form'
```

в данном примере подразумевается, что файл партиала находится в директории `app/views/todos/_todo_form.html.erb` ([Партиалы](http://rusrails.ru/action-view-overview#partialy)):

```
# app/views/todos/_todo_form.html.erb
<div id='todo-form'>
  <%= form_for :todo, url: project_todos_path do |form| %>
    <p>
      <%= form.label :project_id %>
      <%= form.collection_select :project_id, Project.all, :id, :title %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= form.label :text %>
      <%= form.text_field :text %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

при отправке формы будет вызван экшн `create` контроллера `TodoControllers`:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if @todo.save
      # если todo сохранилась
    else
      # если todo не сохранилась
    end
  end
end
```

Про контроллеры тоже почитайте([Контроллеры](http://rusrails.ru/action-controller-overview)). Стронг параметры и всякое такое. Про роутинг.
Это общие заметки для старта Вам. А вообще не пожалейте пару дней почитать официальную документацию, она довольно подробная. [rusrails.ru](http://rusrails.ru/)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74080/discussion-on-answer-by-yauhen---create---select--index-view).