# Реализовать форму без редиректа

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Недавно начал учить Ruby on Rails, сейчас необходимо сделать форму для добавления нового todo, принадлежащего project

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :todos
end

class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Прикрепляю так же скрины с тем как есть(1) и как должно быть (2). Прошерстил уже кучу сайтов и пересмотрел кучу видео, но нигде не могу найти как сделать форму на заглавной странице, чтобы она не перенаправляла на new или show, а просто добавляла новую задачу к уже существующему проекту.
[image: Вот так есть]
[image: Вот так должно получиться]

Comment: Как звучит задача - просто добавить форму на главную страницу или заставить её работать без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: На сайте [довольно много вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=todos+%5Bruby-on-rails%5D) по этому странноватому заданию, проглядите их, найдёте много полезного. Особенно вам поможет вот этот - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793899/Как-создать-create-форму-с-select-в-index-view